# deep-learning-modelsの画像認識時間

Tags: raspberry-pi, 機械学習, tensorflow, keras

下記のサイトを見ながら画像認識を試しています。
[Raspberry Pi 深層学習ライブラリで物体認識 (Keras with TensorFlow・Open CV)](https://qiita.com/PonDad/items/c5419c164b4f2efee368)

学習済みモデルh5とjsonをダウンロードして同じ階層に置き、inception_v3のh5のリンク先をローカルに書き換えました。

```
WEIGHTS_PATH        = 'inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'
WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP = 'inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
```

サイトにはラズパイでも1, 2秒で認識すると記載されていますが実際には1, 2分かかってしまいます。
どこがいけないのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

補足：
h5とjsonは初回動作時にダウンロードしてくれませんでしたので自分でダウンロードしてきました。

h5py 2.7.1
keras 2.1.2
tensorflow 1.4.1
opencv 3.4.1
python 3.5.3

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/120409

Comment: @banban 私のノートパソコンで試してみましたが、一度モデルをダウンロードしておけば Inception_v3 の実行は一瞬で終了し、elaphant.jpg の認識ができました。実行する際に行った手順をひとつずつ追記してくださると、何かお助けできるかもしれません。

Comment: @nekketsuu 実行には仮想環境を使用しています。$source ~/.profile $workon cv $cd deep-learning-models $python inception=v3.py だけです。特に変わった事をしてはいないと思うのですがどうでしょう？もし足らない情報がありましたら追記します。

Comment: 確認なのですが、モデルはあらかじめダウンロードした上で実行なさっていますか？　モデルがローカルに無い場合、モデルのダウンロードに時間がかかります。

Comment: はい。cloneして置いてあります。h5とjsonもdeep-learning-modelsの中に一緒に入れてます。